# Failing to get remote JSON using JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to retrieve a remote JSON using jQuery 1.11.1. The remote server *does* support jsonp and I'm able to download the .jsonp file by simply entering the call address and `?callback=foo` in a browser.

However, when I try to get it using ajax, it fails.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://path-to-remote-server.net/file.jsonp",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "e",
    success: function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    }
});
```

A quick look at the console tells me that it's a bad request, probably because it seems that jQuery passes a second unwanted parameter, making the request look like this :

`http://path-to-remote-server.net/file.jsonp?callback=e&_=1406722474006`

This happens even when I omit the jsonp and jsonpCallback options. The request then looks like this :

`http://path-to-remote-server.net/file.jsonp?callback=jQuery111106199050471186638_1406722685544&_=1406722685545`

Using the short cut $.getJSON doesn't work either, but not for the same reason it seems :

```
$.getJSON("http://path-to-remote-server.net/file.jsonp?callback=e", function(r){
    console.log(r);
});
```

This doesn't trigger any error in the console, but nothing gets logged either, as if it didn't get anything back from the server.

Why is that, and how can I avoid it?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: "A quick look to the console tells me that it's a bad request" — What **exactly** does it tell you?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: It's a pretty odd server that starts throwing `400` errors when you add extra query string arguments.

Comment: You don't need the `jsonp` key/value because this is already defaulted to `callback`, and I'd recommend removing the `jsonpCallback` key/value too and letting jQuery handle that automatically for you.

Comment: I tried it at first, but weirdly the server doesn't seem to like it when I let jQuery handle the callback automatically and throws an error. Also, is there a way to manually pass a second specific parameter _after_ the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

So add `cache: true` to your Ajax parameters.

Comment: This seems to fix my problem! Thanks!

Comment: However, as I retrieve the remote json every X seconds, it could have been a problem to turn the cache on. The server seems to somehow handle this on its own, as the browser doesn't seem to cache the data.

Answer (score -1):

The last query string argument automatically added by jQuery is needed to avoid browser caching. Otherwise if you do the same JSONP call in the same or in any other page of your site, you will get the cached result instead of the fresh one. So if your server does support JSONP it should accept such requests.

It seems to be a server-side issue, so you should check what is going on there :)

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's for what I said about caching, please note that it is exactly what the OP has noticed right now in the above comment by setting `cache: true`... The server caches the response and handles all next request by itself, so you don't get a fresh response for every request, leading to potentially unexpected results

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I wanted to say "The browser caches the response", not "The server"